# ACCESS denied error while GRANTing privileges

Tags: mysql

I want to allow remote connection from a certain IP.

I have a use `coszi_crawl` and DB name is same too.

I am logged into server using `coszi_crawl` user.

I have run this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON coszi_crawl.* TO 'coszi_crawl'@'39.32.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'abcqwe' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But this is giving me this error

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'coszi_crawl'@'localhost' to database 'coszi_crawl'
```

**P.S.:**

Though I can access `coszi_crawl` DB from Browser using PHPmyadmin with user `coszi_crawl`

How can I can solve this problem?

Comment: So therefore `coszi_crawl` does not have the permissions to grant privilages. Use the `root` user

Answer (score 1):

You should use the root account on your database server to update the priviledges, by default the user `coszi_crawl`does not have access to granting priviledges on databases.

Answer (score 1):

It means You don't have **GRANT OPTION** privilege. Login to user having **GRANT OPTION** privileges, only that user can give grant to other users.

Generally or by default root user has all the privileges so use that user.

[Grant privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option)